# CLion and Yaml-cpp: how can i build yaml-cpp with clion in windows

Tags: clion, yaml-cpp

I had install `yaml-cpp` in linux successfully, then i want to install `yaml-cpp` in windows with clion. But when I build or install it, some errors happened. Such as:

```
 In file included from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h:74:0,
                 from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h:53,
                 from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h:44,
                 from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:45,
                 from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:46,
                 from D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
                 from D:\github\yaml-cpp\test\gtest-1.8.0\googlemock\src\gmock-all.cc:40:
D:/github/yaml-cpp/test/gtest-1.8.0/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1782:3: error: 'AutoHandle' does not name a type
```

Is there something I should modify if I want to use `yaml-cpp` in windows?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with MinGW: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intellij-support has [solved](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000410844-how-to-generate-lib-and-include-lib-on-windows-) this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable testing support during CMake configuration via -DYAML_CPP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF.
Seems bundled gtest [has issues with MinGW compatibility](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/606).